# Read from a hive table and write back to it using spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a Hive table using Spark SQL and assigning it to a scala val

```
val x = sqlContext.sql("select * from some_table")
```

Then I am doing some processing with the dataframe x and finally coming up with a dataframe y , which has the exact schema as the table some_table.

Finally I am trying to insert overwrite the y dataframe to the same hive table some_table

```
y.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable().insertInto("some_table")
```

Then I am getting the error

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot insert overwrite into table that is also being read from

I tried creating an insert sql statement and firing it using sqlContext.sql() but it too gave me the same error.

Is there any way I can bypass this error? I need to insert the records back to the same table.

---

Hi I tried doing as suggested , but still getting the same error .

```
val x = sqlContext.sql("select * from incremental.test2")
val y = x.limit(5)
y.registerTempTable("temp_table")
val dy = sqlContext.table("temp_table")
dy.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("incremental.test2")

scala> dy.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("incremental.test2")
             org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot insert overwrite into table that is also being read from.;
```

Comment: I know this is clunky but can you not truncate the original table and then write everything back to it?

Answer (score 12):

You should first save your DataFrame `y` in a temporary table

```
y.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp_table")
```

Then you can overwrite rows in your target table

```
val dy = sqlContext.table("temp_table")
dy.write.mode("overwrite").insertInto("some_table")
```

Comment: Got the same error again . Edited my question with the code snippet

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer. registerAsTempTable will create a in-memory table, thus giving the same error. With saveAsTable it should work (but it is then written to disk, you'll have to drop the table afterwards). Sorry, I don't see other alternatives

Comment: Ya , I have handled the situation with the same logic but i feel its not cost efficient.  The point you highlighted , writing to disk , is the part which i would love to skip.  Anyways thanks for your help @cheseaux . Let me know if you find something good on this . Cheers!!

Comment: Is this totally safe? what if the app fails when writing the destination table? wouldn't it be empty as a result anyways? (so when yarn auto-retries your app, you might be delivering wrong results)

Answer (score 12):

Actually you can also use checkpointing to achieve this. Since it breaks data lineage, Spark is not able to detect that you are reading and overwriting in the same table:

```
 sqlContext.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(checkpointDir)
 val ds = sqlContext.sql("select * from some_table").checkpoint()
 ds.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("some_table")
```

Comment: I tried to do it, and it not work

Answer (score 1):

You should first save your `DataFrame y` like a parquet file:

```
y.write.parquet("temp_table")
```

After you load this like:

```
val parquetFile = sqlContext.read.parquet("temp_table")
```

And finish you insert your data in your table

```
parquetFile.write.insertInto("some_table")
```

Answer (score 1):

In context to Spark 2.2

1. This error means that our process is reading from same table and writing to same table.
2. Normally, this should work as process writes to directory .hiveStaging...
3. This error occurs in case of saveAsTable method, as it overwrites entire table instead of individual partitions.
4. This error should not occur with insertInto method, as it overwrites partitions not the table.
5. A reason why this happening is because Hive table has following Spark TBLProperties in its definition. This problem will solve for insertInto method if you remove following Spark TBLProperties -

> 'spark.sql.partitionProvider' 'spark.sql.sources.provider'
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts' 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.1' 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.2'
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'
> 'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'

https://querydb.blogspot.com/2019/07/read-from-hive-table-and-write-back-to.html

when we upgraded our HDP to 2.6.3 The Spark was updated from 2.2 to 2.3 which resulted in below error -

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from.;

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DDLUtils$.verifyNotReadPath(ddl.scala:906)
```

This error occurs for job where-in we are reading and writing to same path. Like Jobs with SCD Logic

Solution -

1. Set --conf "spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false"
2. or, update the job such that it writes data to a temporary table. Then reads from temporary table and insert it into final table.

https://querydb.blogspot.com/2020/09/orgapachesparksqlanalysisexception.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from hive table in spark:

```
val hconfig = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(hconfig , "dbname", "tablename")

val inputFormat = (new HCatInputFormat).asInstanceOf[InputFormat[WritableComparable[_],HCatRecord]].getClass

val data = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hconfig,inputFormat,classOf[WritableComparable[_]],classOf[HCatRecord])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also get the Error: "Cannot overwrite a path that is also being read from" in a case where your are doing this:

1. You are "insert overwrite" to a hive TABLE "A" from a VIEW "V" (that executes your logic)
2. And that VIEW also references the same TABLE "A". I found this the hard way as the VIEW is  deeply nested code that was querying "A" as well. Bummer.

It is like cutting the very branch on which you are sitting :-(

Answer (score 0):

What you need to keep in mind before doing below is that the hive table in which you are overwriting should be have been created by hive DDL not by

```
spark(df.write.saveAsTable("<table_name>"))
```

if the above is not true this wont work.
I tested this in spark 2.3.0

```
val tableReadDf=spark.sql("select * from <dbName>.<tableName>")
val updatedDf=tableReadDf.<transformation> //any update/delete/addition 
updatedDf.createOrReplaceTempView("myUpdatedTable")
spark.sql("""with tempView as(select * from myUpdatedTable) insert overwrite table 
<dbName>.<tableName> <partition><partition_columns> select * from tempView""")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is good solution for me:

1. Extract RDD and schema from DataFrame.
2. Create new clone DataFame.
3. Overwrite table.

   ```
    private def overWrite(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
      val schema = df.schema
      val rdd    = df.rdd
      val dfForSave = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
      dfForSave.write
               .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
               .insertInto(s"${tableSource.schema}.${tableSource.table}")}
   ```